# how nodejs sent a value of a variable to angular4 component

Tags: node.js, angular

**app.js**

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
    // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
    console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
    res.render('message',{msg:'email has been sent'});
});
```

**component.html**

```
<form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit(userForm.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" name="who" ngModel>
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" ngModel>
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">I'll never share your email with anyone else.</small><br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here..." name="message" ngModel>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sent Mail</button>
</form>
{{msg}}
```

**component.ts**

```
export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor( private http:Http) { }
  ngOnInit() { 
  }
   onSubmit = function (user) {
    console.log(user);
    //this.http.post('http://xxx/externalapi/add', user);
    let parm=JSON.stringify(user);
    console.log(parm);
    let headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    this.http.post("/api/send", parm, options).subscribe(data => {
    });
  }
```

> I want to sent message using angular4 via email. I can sent successfully. after
>   that I want to sent successful message to client from app.js. but I
>   don't know how I have to do?
>    I want to sent value to {msg} variable that is in my component.html page

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js file you don't need res.render. You aren't rendering a page. All you need to send is some quick JSON data. So, instead of `res.render()`. Use something like `res.json()` [See here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

Next, all you need to do is listen for the response in your component and handle it.

```
this.http.post("/api/send", parm, options).subscribe(data => {
  this.msg = data.message; // Or Handle however you want. You should also handle errors
});
```

Comment: It's still not working. am I have to use angular service?

Comment: Ok. What's happening now? you might actually need to use `data.body.message` I'm can't remember for sure. Try console.logging the data and let us know what's happening now.

Answer (score 0):

> Thank you. I solved it. I used this to sent response.

res.json({"msg":"message sent"});

> And I grab response using `.map(res=>this.mesg =res.json())`